# Replacement for DOS xcopy command

Tags: command-line, bash, clipboard

In DOS there's the command

`xcopy /s *.mp3 ..\TEMP2`

How can I do this in Ubuntu?

`cp -r *.mp3 ../TEMP2`

will copy recursively all mp3 files, unfortunately without the path because of the `*.mp3` filter.

`cp -r *.* ../TEMP2`

will copy the path but can not be limited to mp3 files

I had a look at rsync, but I don't get it.

Comment: Do you want to copy the mp3 files WITHOUT the directory to the temp2 folder or do you want to copy them WITH the directory.

Comment: @Luis: I guess he wants to preserve the directory structure, or else cp -r would have worked.

Comment: some nifty commands below. But what is wrong with good old `tar`, a move and an `untar` :D

Comment: What shell are you using? The second command will only copy the mp3 files in the current directory (and any directories named `.mp3` -- it will *not* recursively copy all mp3 files.

Comment: Indeed I want to preserve directory structure.

Comment: I have just seen this similar question with a different and interesting solution: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19841/recursively-copy-only-images-and-preserve-path/

Answer (score 8):

The power of tools in Ubuntu is that you can combine them.  The next command finds all .mp3 files in the current directory and its subdirectories, and copies them to the `../TEMP2/` folder, preserving paths:

```
find -iname '*.mp3' -exec install -D {} ../TEMP2/{} \;
```

- `find -iname '*.mp3'` - finds all files ending with `.mp3` (case-insensitive) and

  - `-exec` - executes a command for each match:

    - `install -D {} ../TEMP2/{}` - copies the matched file to `../TEMP/` preserving the path. (`{}` is replaced by the path including filename)
  - `\;` - ends the `-exec` command

If you want to get the progress, add `-ls` ("list") to the command before `-exec`. It can be put after `\;` too, but in that case the name is shown after being copied. Examples:

```
find -iname '*.mp3' -ls -exec install -D {} ../TEMP2/{} \;
find -iname '*.mp3' -exec install -D {} ../TEMP2/{} \; -ls
```

Comment: I dont understand why would this be any different than `rsync -r`, except using a much more complex syntax

Comment: I'm not that familiar with rsync, so this is the best command I could think of.

Comment: I suppose you need a `-D` option to `install`.

Comment: This one does not copy the subdir.

Comment: @sleepless Please try again, I was missing the `-D` option which would create any directories if needed.

Comment: Yes lekenstein, both constructions work and I like to see the progress, thats a good addition. But I discoverd, if one of the files is hidden, it is skipped, how to solve that?

Comment: @sleepless: I cannot confirm your findings, `find` shows hidden files (like `.hidden.mp3` as well as `.hiddenfolder/file.mp3`) for me. Perhaps your file browser hide it for you? If you're using the `ls` command, add the `-A` option to show dotfiles too.

Comment: You are completely right, sorry for this stupidity.

Comment: Someone suggested to use quotes as in `-exec ... "{}" \;`. This is not necessary as {} correctly expands into a single argument. `"{}"` still works because the quotes are eaten by bash.

Answer (score 3):

There are several options, but none is really simple, I'm afraid…

### rsync

```
rsync -r --include="*/" --include="*.mp3" --exclude="*" --prune-empty-dirs . ../TEMP2
```

This tells to exclude all files (`exclude="*"`), but to look into all directories (`include="*/"`) and to include all mp3 files (`include="*.mp3"`). If you do not want to copy directories not containing any mp3 files, in addition the `--prune-empty-dirs` option is necessary.

### zip

```
zip -R archive.zip "*.mp3"
unzip -d ../TEMP2 archive.zip && rm archive.zip
```

The first command creates an archive with all mp3 files, the second unzips the content to the target directory and deletes the archive file if it was successful.

### find

```
find . -iname "*.mp3" -exec install -D {} ../TEMP2/{} ";"
```

This will find all mp3 files and copy them to the corresponding path in the `../TEMP2` directory, after creating the directory structure first (`install -D`).

### copy all and delete the rest

This only makes sense if you have just a few files that you *don't* want to copy:

```
cp -r * ../TEMP2
find ../TEMP2 -type f \! -iname '*.mp3' -delete
```

This copies everything and then deletes all files that are not mp3 files

Comment: Yes your find construction works too! I like that one the most. It's a great learning experience. I have come to the right place. But the forum software is very user unfriendly. Rinus

Comment: lekenstein's find -iname '*.mp3' -exec install -D {} ../TEMP2/{} \;  with enzotib's "-D" got it going to work.
Marcel Stimbergs work is excellent.
That means after two days searching solved with your help. You are amazing. Thanks a lot even for the contribs that did not work. Solved!
Rinus